# Smallest triangular number with prime signature the same as A025487(n)

Tags: number-theory

Smallest triangular number with prime signature the same as [A025487](https://oeis.org/A025487)(n), or 0 if no such number exists. (there is a similar sequence [A081978](https://oeis.org/A081978))

For n = 1 through n = 29, this sequence is: (I have not confirmed the n = 15 term is 0, but it seems that it is 0, i.e. it seems that there is no triangular number of the form p^3*q^2 with p, q both primes)

1, 3, 0, 6, 0, 28, 0, 136, 66, 0, 36, 496, 276, 0, 0, 118341, 120, 0, 1631432881, 300, 8128, 210, 0, 528, 0, 29403, 1176, 32896, 630

Is it possible to extend this sequence to n = 100?